# Potted lemon tree not growing/flowering

Tags: growth, citrus, repotting, flowering, lemons

I bought a potted lemon tree (>1m tall)and I had it indoors until the weather was good enough to then move it onto the balcony (west facing).
Since I bought the tree (2 months ago) I have seen little to no growth, no flowers, and no new shoots/buds.

After a month more or less I repotted the tree because the roots were coming out of the bottom of the pot. The new pot is 25% bigger than the previous one and the roots looked very healthy.
I am also using citrus feed following the instructions on the bottle.

Is this normal for a lemon tree and I need to be patient or am I doing something wrong?
In the pics, you can see the tree when I bought it (indoors) and how it is now (outdoors).
I’d appreciate any recommendation since it’s the first time I take care of a citrus tree!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your tree looks happy. Shiny leaves are a good sign. Your tree was grown in subtropical sun or greenhouse and your exposure may not compare. Bringing a plant home shocks it. Transplanting shocks it. Annual transplanting is not needed.

Comment: Oh, I’m pleased to hear that! 
And thank you so much for the info and suggestions.